# Path Error when including a .jade file in a template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

folder structure:

```
./jglobal/common.jade
./site1/template.jade
```

template.jade:

```
doctype html
html(lang='#{meta.lang_code}')
  head
    include ../jglobal/common
```

When I render the template via commandline mode, I got this error:

`the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths`

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Comment: try `include /jglobal/common`

Comment: tells me `the "basedir" option is required to use "include" with "absolute" paths`

Comment: Well, it finally works! I pass in the `__dirname` as the value of `basedir`

Comment: Done this (added the basedir with __dirname). It still cries with the "basedir" option is required to use "include" with "absolute" paths.
Other dynamic properties works perfectly)
WHY IS IT SO HARD??? Include is what it is all about, isn't it?